# Dnn, Client ResourceManagment - path to module

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

How do i register the MapInitializer script if its located in the root of the module.?
Are installed modules always located in the desktopmodules/modulename ?  (> DNN v6.1)

```
<%@ Control language="C#" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Modules.wwp_gmap_module.View"
AutoEventWireup="false"  Codebehind="View.ascx.cs" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement"
Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>


<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="MapInitializer.js"  />

<div id="Map_Canvas" >
</div>

<asp:Literal ID="lrlStatusMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installed modules are always located in the `DesktopModules` folder; the folder name within `DesktopModules` is usually, but not always, the same as the module name.  You should be able to find the folder name in your module's manifest (.dnn file).

Unfortunately, the `DnnJsInclude` (and `DnnCssInclude`) control doesn't support relative paths ([as of DNN 6.1.2, currently set to be fixed in DNN 6.2.0](http://support.dotnetnuke.com/Default.aspx?p=2&i=19020)), so you *will* need to set the `FilePath` property to include the module name (e.g. `FilePath="~/DesktopModules/wwp_gmap_module/js/MapInitializer.js"`).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with following approach:
                ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page,
    string.Format("http://{0}/{1}/Js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js",
    Request.Url.Host, this.TemplateSourceDirectory), 110, "DnnPageHeaderProvider");

Comment: I would recommend using `DotNetNuke.Web.Client.FileOrder.Js.DefaultPriority` instead of hard-coding the meaningless `110`.  I'd also suggest using the default body provider, unless you really need your script in the head (running your script later in the page will result in a greater perception of page speed, typically); to do that, just use the overload of `RegisterScript` that takes two arguments.  Finally, you should be able to use `ResolveUrl` in this context to avoid messing with the full path in your code, e.g. `ResolveUrl("js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js")` instead of `string.Format`.